# Adding event listeners to 'memory objects' in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, listener, dom-events

Some background to the problem:
[Reverse Engineering the DOM, Javascript events & "what's going on"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240416/reverse-engineering-the-dom-javascript-events-whats-going-on)

I'm writing something that will 'play' with the functionality of google's page preview on live search.  Essentially, I'd like to add an event listener to the keyup event that will

1. query the page preview results (send an ajax request to google)
2. read that result in memory
3. add it to your search page in realtime

This will essentially create a live page preview search result would of google.

To be fair, I've actually got about 95% of this working in various components and I'm at the stages of tweaking functionality to make it a bit more user friendly.  If you're interested in the whys and hows of what I'm doing, please feel free to check out a my previous blog posts at http://chesser.ca or even look at the 'latest version of the code' at http://chesser.ca/gvs.marklet.0.3.js (currently very buggy as i'm a bit "between functionalities" at the moment.

The bookmarklet code for your browser is here:

```
 javascript:(function{var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];var script= document.createElement('script');script.type= 'text/javascript';script.src= 'http://chesser.ca/gvs.marklet.0.3.js';head.appendChild(script);};)();
```

(the keyup event listener is currently set to off, essentially to make it work in its current state, you run a search on a page with live preview and click the bookmarklet once (to initiate queries), wait a second or two, then click it a second time (to display the page previews)

So I've got some changes to this to make:

In part 1 (for performance) I'm interested in only querying the first two elements.  I imagine that will be easy and the only thing stopping me is that I haven't tried it yet (instead of all divs.length, just set it to 2)

```
function query_current_pages(){
     var all_divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
     for (i=0;i < all_divs.length; i++) {
         if (all_divs[i].className == 'vsc') {
             google.vs.ea(all_divs[i]);
         }
     }
 }
```

The next problem (and the one that I'm a not sure about) is how I can set up an event listener and modify the add_previews function such that the previews are added when the request comes back, instead of the rather ham-fisted approach of looping through everything that is in the `google.vs.ha` memory space rather I'd like to create something that will listen for the data to be there and then spring into action.

The *reason* i'm trying to do this is because I think it would be really really neat.  That and I've learned a 'mountain' of stuff about coding while doing it.

For those interested in how the page previews get "chucked on the page" here's the function that loops through all the images in memory and put them up.

```
 function add_previews(){
    c=document.getElementById('ires');
    nli=document.createElement('div');
    cell = 0;
    for(var Obj in google.vs.ha){
        na=document.createElement('a');
        na.href=Obj;

        nd=document.createElement('div');
        cldiv=document.createElement('div');
        cldiv.style.clear = 'both';

        nd.style.width=google.vs.ha[Obj].data.dim[0]+'px';
        nd.style.height=google.vs.ha[Obj].data.dim[1]+'px';
        nd.style.margin = '5px';
        nd.style.padding = '5px';
        nd.style.cssFloat = 'left';
        nd.style.border = '1px solid #999999';

        if (google.vs.ha[Obj].data.tbts.length) {
            nilDiv = document.createElement('div'); 
            for(i = 0; i < google.vs.ha[Obj].data.tbts.length; i++){
                box = google.vs.ha[Obj].data.tbts[i].box;
                newbox = document.createElement('div');
                newbox.className = 'vsb vsbb';
                newbox.style.position = 'relative';
                newbox.style.top = (box.t)+'px';
                newbox.style.left = box.l+'px';
                newbox.style.height = box.h+'px';
                newbox.style.width = box.w+'px';
                nilDiv.appendChild(newbox);
                newtext = document.createElement('div');
                newtext.className = 'vsb vstb';
                newtext.innerHTML = google.vs.ha[Obj].data.tbts[i].txt;
                newtext.style.top = (box.t)+'px';
                newtext.style.position = 'relative';
                nilDiv.appendChild(newtext);
            }
            nilDiv.style.height = '0px';
            nd.appendChild(nilDiv);
        }

        for(i = 0; i < google.vs.ha[Obj].data.ssegs.length; i++){
            ni=document.createElement('img');
            ni.src += google.vs.ha[Obj].data.ssegs[i];
            ni.className+=' vsi';
            na.appendChild(ni);
        }
        nd.appendChild(na);
        nli.appendChild(nd);
    };
    c.insertBefore(nli,c.firstChild);           
 }
```

The obvious bit to change in there (with an event listener) is to fix `for(var Obj in google.vs.ha){` to be a single `google.vs.rs` object that is passed in.

If you've lasted this far into the question: thanks for reading :)
- Alex

**EDIT**

As per the discussion below, google.vs.Ga seems to be responsible for querying the data (to which the answer is over-writing the function)

For informational purposes (and fun) here's the .Ga code.

```
  google.vs.Ga = function (a, b, c) {
        var d = google.vs.b.kfe.kfeHost,
            g = google.vs.Ya(a),
            i = a.getAttribute("sig");
        if (i) {
            var f = google.vs.qa(a);
            if (f) {
                d = [d ? "http://" + d : "", google.vs.b.kfe.kfeUrlPrefix, "&d=", encodeURIComponent(f), "&b=1", "&jsonp=google.vs.r"];
                d.push("&a=");
                d.push(encodeURIComponent(i));
                if (i = a.getAttribute("blobref")) {
                    d.push("&bl=");
                    d.push(i)
                }
                d.push("&rs=");
                i = 0;
                for (var j; j = g[i++];) {
                    d.push(encodeURIComponent(j));
                    i < g.length && d.push("&rs=")
                }
                g = google.vs.m(a) || {
                    ub: a
                };
                g.G = c;
                google.vs.ha[f] = g;
                c = d.join("");
                c = new google.vs.Ia(f, c, function () {
                    google.vs.P(a, h);
                    o(google.vs.k, f)
                });
                b ? p(google.vs.k, c) : q(google.vs.k, c)
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: I'm a little confused - what function would the event be calling when data is updated?

Comment: are you trying to determine when the preview image is available, and have that trigger the event that you are looking for?

Comment: @matt - yes - trying to figure out when the image is available and trigger at that time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The google.vs.ha object is a basic JavaScript object, with key/value pair attributes, and no functions to speak of.  That being said, these simple objects are not capable of notifying you when they are changed.

The way I see it, you basically have 2 options:

- Periodically check google.vs.ha for the data that you are looking for, keeping track of which ones you've already grabbed the images. This could be accomplished with setInterval();
- Determine which function on the page or in the google. namespace is responsible for doing the work of loading the data.  Once you determine where the data is getting loaded, and where, exactly, the google.vs.ha objects are getting updated, you can replace the original function with one of your own crafting that contains an event notification.

For example, if I have a basic function that looks like this:

```
var Example = function(value){
  var closured = ' world';
  this.value = value;
  this.doSomething = function(){ alert(this.value + closured); };
};

var test = new Example('hello');
test.doSomething(); // will only alert 'hello world';

var oldFunc = test.doSomething;
var notifyMe = function(){ alert('notified'); }; // callback function

// Update previous method to do it's normal thing, but then notify after
test.doSomething = function(){
  oldFunc.apply(this, arguments);
  notifyMe();
};

test.doSomething(); // will alert 'hello world', and then 'notified'
```

In the above code, we have effectively replaced the old doSomething function with one of our own.  This new version still performs it's previous duties (via oldFunc.apply), but will then notify you afterwards.

Note that your new function will only have access to the objects 'public' properties, and not the private elements that are captured by a closure (such as the 'closured' var).  I seem to remember somewhere that Google tends to avoid private variables as closures approach, due to the complexities this can add to memory management, so that may not be an issue.

UPDATE: I played around a bit with it on a Google search results page.  I ran a fresh search, but before clicking on the preview, I executed in the Chrome console the following:

```
var old = google.vs.Ga;
var newFunc = function(){
  old.apply(this, arguments);
  console.log(arguments);
};

google.vs.Ga = newFunc;
```

And it seemed to be triggered after clicking preview.

Comment: Overriding one of google's functions seems like a good idea, but I wouldn't yet bet on them too keep current implementation unchanged. It's a fresh thing I guess. Still the Update you put here is a really clean way to do it. +1 from me.

Comment: yes - google.vs.ea calls google.vs.Ga so you're saying that I can use Javascript to copy the existing Ga then add my own line of code after it?  IIRC .ga isn't quite the one that returns the resultset - but it's close.   If I know how to overwrite the function, I'm sure I can find the right one to take care of.   I'll be sure to let you know :)

Comment: @naugtur true, but when you're building JavaScript to manipulate the data on the page it will always be dependent on if they change their implementation.  Some things may be more likely to break than others, but in the end you still have to make an assumption in order to get the job done.

Comment: @Alex C yes, that is correct.  I didn't follow the breadcrumb trail on google.vs.Ga, but it seems like a decent place to start

Comment: @naugtur - excellent point, fortunately in this case it's more for the purposes of exploration, learning and enjoyment of coding.  I really only have to see the live-preview search work properly once and I'll be satisfied. (This is really a case of art for art's sake) - I love the way Matt's shown us how to override the default behavior of a function.

Comment: @Mat - I said it in the context of it being a new feature. I expect the implementation to undergo some changes in coming month(s?) and hooking up to ajax calls, not a single function, might be a bit more general. @Alex C - Yet Matt's idea is much cleaner, so I honestly recommend it :)

Answer (score 1):

The images are stored SINCE they are downloaded, right? Obvious.
So the only moment that they can change is an AJAX request.

Therefore you have to run some checking-up everytime an AJAX request succeeds. jQuery has global bindings for successful AJAX calls, so it should be possible even without it.

Now when we know this - the checking-up might start from seeing what was the type of the call by some variables avaliable in the response object, or the XMLHTTPRequest object itself. This could narrow down the number of times you have to call your updater even more.

Comment: Interestingly - they come in as data URIs.  the function `google.vs.ea(div[@class=vsc]);`  calls an ajax request which loads the data into memory.  The visual search blog did say that browsers chache this data somewhere - but I've seen the ajax requests seem to happen every time.  According to Matt below, It looks like my course of action might be to overwrite one of google's functions with one of my own.

Comment: "calls an ajax request which loads the data into memory" - and why not hook to that?